# error TS2322: Property 'css' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I've recently decided to move my codebase from JS to TS to add Type checking. I also use the `styled-components` library.

However, i'm running into the following issue:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ children: string; css: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'css' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
```

Here is a basic code example:

```
import React from 'react'
const MyComponent: React.FC = (props) => {
    return (
        <div css={`
            padding: 44px;
        `}>
            My content
        </div>
    )
}
```

Please note that my `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions` look like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist", // https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outFile
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "jsx":"react",
        "types": ["@types/styled-components"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        
        "declarationMap": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noUnusedLocals":true,
        "noUnusedParameters":true,
        "allowJs":true,
        "noEmit": false
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve the type of the `css` attribute ?

Comment: The attribute you are looking for is `style` instead `css`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `styledComponentsOverride.d.ts` with following code inside:

```
import { CSSProp } from 'styled-components'

interface MyTheme {}

declare module 'react' {
    interface Attributes {
       css?: CSSProp<MyTheme>
    }
}
```

This will extend react element attributes types with optional CSS prop

more info: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31245

Answer (score 3):

Why not just add this line in the 'style.d.ts' file?

```
import {} from 'styled-components/cssprop'
```

Comment: I added this into my global.d.ts file, and this resolved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is experiencing this issue while using [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/babel), see the equivalent type declaration module:

```
import type { SerializedStyles } from "@emotion/serialize";
import type { DOMAttributes } from "react";

declare module "react" {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
        css?: SerializedStyles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jkaczmarkiewicz ! This works great. Updated it to :

```
import { CSSProp } from "styled-components";

interface DefaultTheme {}

declare module "react" {
   interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
     css?: CSSProp<DefaultTheme>;
   }
 }
```

In addition to the link you provided, this [issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2528) might help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a similar, but slightly different way. I added a styled.d.ts file in the src/theme folder. You can also just put it straight in the src file if you're not using a theme.

Then I added the following code in this file:

```
import { CSSObject } from 'styled-components';
import { CSSProp } from 'styled-components';
declare module 'react' {
  interface Attributes {
    css?: CSSProp | CSSObject;
  }
}
```

**Sources**

- https://medium.com/@luxtars.dev/use-styled-components-with-typescript-73b703261d9e
- https://dev.to/rajuashok/create-styled-d-ts-to-make-typescript-work-with-styled-components-5dk4

Answer (score 0):

In emotion you can create the following `cssTypes.d.ts`

```
import { Interpolation } from '@emotion/react';

interface DefaultTheme {}

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
    css?: Interpolation<DefaultTheme>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "Property 'css' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps'" typically occurs when you're trying to use the css prop in a TypeScript project without properly setting up the types for your styling library.

Here are some steps you can take to resolve this issue:

Update Your TypeScript Configuration

If you're using a library like Emotion or Styled Components, you need to include their types in your TypeScript configuration. For example, if you're using Emotion, you can add "@emotion/react" to the types array in your

> tsconfig.json

file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@emotion/react"]
  }
}
```

Declare CSS Prop in a Type Declaration File

You can declare the css prop in a type declaration file

> (.d.ts)

. This tells TypeScript that the css prop exists on all HTML elements. Here's an example of how to do this:

```
import { CSSProp } from 'styled-components'

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
    css?: CSSProp;
  }
}
```

In this code, CSSProp is imported from styled-components, and the css prop is added to the HTMLAttributes interface from react.

Reinstall Dependencies

If you're still encountering the issue after updating your TypeScript configuration and declaring the css prop, you might need to reinstall your dependencies. You can do this by deleting your node_modules folder and running npm install or yarn install again.

**Update Your TypeScript Version**

If you're using the new JSX transform introduced in React 17, you might need to update your TypeScript version to 4.1 or later. This version of TypeScript includes support for the new JSX transform.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the "Property 'css' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps'" error in your TypeScript project. If you continue to experience issues, please provide more details about your code and the context in which you're using the css prop, and I'll be happy to provide further assistance.